# Whole of button not clickable

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the JSFiddle when you try and click the button and not the 'More' the link doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/CM5e8/

Scss

```
button {
padding: 8px 20px;
border: 0;
@include border-radius(6px);
font-size: 0.8em;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;


a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}

.green {
background: #9fd468;
display: block;

&:hover {
    background: #ace175;
}

&:active {
    @include box-shadow (inset 2px 2px 1px #759f49);
}
}
```

html

```
<button class="green">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<a>` tag is only around the text in the button, so in order to make the whole button clickable, you need to wrap the `<a>` tag around the button. Here's the code:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <button class="green">More</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the button in the anchor tag so that the button is a link.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <button class="green">More</button>
</a>
```